# Spring Thymeleaf could not find js/css

Tags: java, spring, resources, thymeleaf

I tried to build a simple Web Application with Spring using the Spring Tool-Suite and Eclipse. As Template I'm using Thymeleaf, but for some weird reason I could not load static files like js or css in my html page.

Update for a minimal example:

folders under src/main/java

```
package com.visualizer.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AlgorithmVisualizerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AlgorithmVisualizerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package com.visualizer.web.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("test");
    }

}
```

my html src/main/resources/templates/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link th:href="@{/css/testLayout.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/testJS.js}"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload=test()>
        <h1>TEST</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

my css found at src/main/resources/static/css/testLayout.css

```
BODY {
    color: green;
}
```

my js found at src/main/resources/static/js/testJS.js

```
function test() {
    console.log("test successfull");
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.visualizer.web'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '16'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

my test.html loads fine, but css and js doesnt load.

Comment: Move there HTML to `src/main/resources/templates`, so that Thymeleaf will serve the page and add `th` tags for the locations.

Answer (score 0):

If you application is running on localhost on port 8080 for example, then check if http://localhost:8080/css/layout.css works.

Also, be sure to use leading slashes here:

```
<link th:href="@{/css/layout.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/layoutCreator.js}"></script>
```

UPDATE:

With your updated question information, I can say this:

Remove the `WebConfig` class that you have and create a controller class instead. For example:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

  @GetMapping("/test")
  public String testPage() {
    return "test"; // this will search for a Thymeleaf template at src/main/resources/templates called test.html
  }
}
```